# VI and VIM list of files

Tags: vim, vi

I accidentally discovered a feature of VI during a long session, a feature that I want to use, but I can't find it in my history.

If I have a list of files all ending with .property, how do I open a list of these files in vi, so that they show as a list that I can scroll down and select the correct file to edit?

I did look back in my history, but I have a million tabs open, and can't find out how I did this!

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`:e <directory containing .property files>`<kbd>Enter</kbd>

This will list all the files in the directory. Now you can navigate to the right file and start editing.

If you are in the directory that contains .property files, then you can just use `:E`<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Then you can use Ctrl+H to edit the hiding list, type `\.property` and press `a` a couple of times to show only those files ending with .property.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend you to try [ctrlp.vim](http://kien.github.io/ctrlp.vim/) It has search by file name or full path, regexp search, automatic detection of the project root (the one with the .git|hg|svn|bzr|_darcs folder), personalized file name exclusions, and many more.

Just press  and it will open a pane where you can search what you want:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
:vnew|r!find . -name *.property
```

The command above opens a new buffer in a new vertical window and populates it with the output of `find`. Use `gf` to jump to the file under the cursor.

```
:args **/*.property
:ls
```

The command above recursively populates the argument list with every file ending with `.property`. Use `:ls` to choose a buffer to edit.